# Large dataframes with many object columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a 2.6 gig data file on a machine with 40 gigs of memory. I would think that I'd have enough memory to work with the data in pandas and yet I run out of memory when I do something as simple as trying to drop a column in place.

All I can think is that the problem is with the nature of the data.

- Dimensions: 634350 x 697
- Number of columns of type object: 467
- Maximum column width: 31072 characters
- Average column width: 100 characters

Are my problems arising from the fact that the object type is just too inefficient?

Comment: in-place operations don't necessarily save you memory, as they are usually implemented as a copy, modify, and replace internally, FYI. You should show a sample frame (you can put in random data), as well as operations you are doing.

Comment: The operation that I'm doing is `df.drop('col', axis=1, inplace=True)`. Memory errors only occur when the dataframe gets very large. Is it still useful to see an excerpt?

Comment: ``dict([ (b.dtype,b.values.nbytes) for b in df._data.blocks ])`` will tell you how much actual memory you are using, can you show that?

Comment: Here it is: {dtype('int64'): 5074800, dtype('float64'): 1162129200, dtype('O'): 2369931600}

Comment: ok, those numbers seem reasonable. The problem is that python needs *contiguous* memory, so each memory allocation will actually be very tricky. I would highly suggest using a smaller number of columns to do your actual work (e.g. break it up) into some pieces. and deal with them separately.

Comment: So would this be the case for any dataframe that is above a certain size or is the number of columns the deciding factor?

Comment: I think the strings might cause it more than say a really large float frame because they are essentially python pointers rather than packed data. Its not the number of columns per se, nor the data size, rather a combination of both. I am assuming you are using a unix type box (and not windows), where all bets would be off.

Comment: Yeah i'm running ubuntu. Maybe I should convert to dummies immediately...

Comment: yes going to suggest that; use a hash (or really just a string to number map); would be vastly more efficient in memory space